# WordPress Page Width Issue: Seeking Solutions

Tags: customization, themes, genesis-theme-framework, static-website, full-site-editing

Hello Google Help Community,

I am facing an issue with my WordPress website, specifically with two pages - "About Us" and "Guest Post."

These pages are currently aligned to the middle and are not displaying in full width as I intend them to. See the below screenshot for better understanding.

"Guest Post Page"

[image]

And below is the "About us" Page

[image]

I've also tried using the Full Width Template plugin in WordPress, but unfortunately, it hasn't resolved the problem. After installing and activating the plugin, I expected to see a "Template" option in the Page Attributes section when editing these pages.

However, there is no such option available, making it challenging to select a full-width template. See below SS for better understanding.

[image]

Can anyone guide me on how to stretch these particular pages to full width? Is there an alternative method or solution I can explore to achieve the desired full-width display for the "About Us" and "Guest Post" pages?

Your assistance and insights are greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You'll have to ask your theme's support team for assistance. Third-party theme support is [off topic](/help/on-topic) here.